# Converting .fbx files to g3dj not working

Tags: libgdx

```
iMac:fbx-conv me$ ./fbx-conv-mac -v -o G3DJ courier.fbx
INFO:     FBX to G3Dx converter, version 0.01.0061 x64 , FBXSDK 2014.02
STATUS:   Loading source file
PROGRESS: Import FBX 100.00%                                                             
STATUS:   Converting source file
STATUS:   Closing source file
VERBOSE:  Listing model information:
VERBOSE:  ID        : 
VERBOSE:  Version   : Hi=0, Lo=1
VERBOSE:  Meshes    : 0 (0 vertices, 0 parts, 0 indices)
VERBOSE:  Nodes     : 0 root, 0 total, 0 parts
VERBOSE:  Materials : 0 (0 textures)
STATUS:   Exporting to G3DJ file: courier.g3dj
STATUS:   Closing exported file
```

I'm using maya lt to export an object to fbx for conversion. 
The 3d model is downloaded from the maya market site, imported and exported to fbx.

The returned .g3dj file is almost empty. Loading it in libgdx

> assets.load("data/courier.g3dj", Model.class);

doesn't show anything either.

Anyone know what went wrong?

.g3dj file:

```
{
    "version": [  0,   1], 
    "id": "", 
    "meshes": [], 
    "materials": [], 
    "nodes": [], 
    "animations": []
}
```

I had some success trying blender which return me this:

```
    iMac:fbx-conv me$ ./fbx-conv-mac -v -o G3DJ palm_tree.fbx
INFO:     FBX to G3Dx converter, version 0.01.0061 x64 , FBXSDK 2014.02
STATUS:   Loading source file
PROGRESS: Import FBX 12.50% palm_tree                                           
PROGRESS: Import FBX 25.00% 02 - Default                                       PROGRESS: Import FBX 37.50% Map #1
PROGRESS: Import FBX 50.00% Map #1
PROGRESS: Import FBX 62.50% Take 001
PROGRESS: Import FBX 75.00% BaseLayer                                  PROGRESS: Import FBX 87.50%                                           PROGRESS: Import FBX 100.00%

STATUS:   [shape(palm_tree)] Triangulating FbxMesh geometry
VERBOSE:  [shape(palm_tree)] polygons: 1032 (3096 indices), control points: 724
STATUS:   Converting source file
STATUS:   Closing source file
VERBOSE:  Listing model information:
VERBOSE:  ID        : 
VERBOSE:  Version   : Hi=0, Lo=1
VERBOSE:  Meshes    : 1 (743 vertices, 1 parts, 3096 indices)
VERBOSE:  Nodes     : 1 root, 1 total, 1 parts
VERBOSE:  Materials : 1 (1 textures)
STATUS:   Exporting to G3DJ file: palm_tree.g3dj
STATUS:   Closing exported file
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but I might suggest posting this in a related forum or using different tags since your error is not related to `libGDX` at all.

Comment: g3d 3d model format is part of the libgdx framework. :)

Comment: I understand however you haven't used the libGDX framework when generating these files (if you have, my bad).

Comment: Create a new project in maya and open the source FBX file you used to make sure it actually contains what you want it to contain. Also, include enough information to actually reproduce the problem you're having, otherwise it's just guessing what you're doing wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xoppa i was hoping you would reply. I was reading up the tutorials from https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/. Let me check what's inside.

Comment: nvm the object is in the new scene. it just doesn't convert to g3dj. would be it the fbx 2016 version that fbx-conv is not supporting?